# How can I make an automatic search filter with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that shows League of Legends icons for champions all in a row.  One of those looks like this:

```
<div class = "champion">
 <p>Aatrox
  <img class = "face_left" src = "images/small/Aatrox.png">
  <div class = "name" onmouseover="if(champ1=='') preview1('Aatrox', 'Aatrox')" onmouseout="if(champ1=='')restoreAvatar1()" onClick="champ1 = 'Aatrox'; preview1('Aatrox', 'Aatrox')">
  </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

And I want to have a search bar above them and when you start typing in the name of the champion, it automatically starts filtering out champions that do not fit what is being searched.  Now, I did find this Javascript snippet and I did mess around with it and get it to work in simpler scenarios in which I simply had one div and a p tag inside, but for some reason with all these divs it doesn't want to filter anything.  This is what the search bar and JS look like:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">

var $rows = $('.champion p');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

Is there any way to get this code to filter out the entire "champion" div with everything inside it?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mQH5z/1/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

jQuery(function(){
    var $rows = $('.champion');
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        var regex =  new RegExp(RegExp.escape($.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')), 'i')
        $rows.hide().filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            return regex.test(text)
        }).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mQH5z/)